# How do I grab all values from a JQuery menu

Tags: jquery, menu

I have a dropdown menu that is populated with key value pairs in php.  Now I want to use JQuery to attach click handlers to each of those keys.

How do I print out a list of the contents in a drop down menu in JQuery?
  (I know to get the current value of the menu as  $(this).val()

I was thinking - maybe iterate through every child element and grab the val?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('select#idselect option').each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
      // do stuff
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses the `change` event, which is more applicable to a select box.

```
$("#select_id").change(function() {
    // get the value
    var value = $(this).val();

    // do something
    alert(value); 
}
```